# Sort From Different Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am not a VBA Macro Programmer, but I know only a little bit. Please help me on this problem.
There are two Workbooks, WorkBookA and WorkBookB.

**WorkbookA:**

[image]

**WorkBookB:**

[image]

The BROWSE tab is to browse WorkBookA, and other Workbook whisch is similar to WorkBookA but different content. REFRESH button will update the 'Checked' or 'Unchecked' Status of the CheckButton.

Comment: @L42 Thnk you. Forgot about the link.

Comment: The only thing missing is what have you tried and where are you having a hard time? That's how SO works. Solve specific programming issues on specific code(s).

Comment: I tried and fail a lot. So now I am thinking to have a fresh start. The images are simplified problems. I'll try to compile everything, and get back to it later. Thank you a lot on the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so clear... If you want only the data checked replicated, you can write a sub like that:

```
Sub UpdateCheck()
    Dim e, i As Integer

    i = 1
    If CheckBox1.Value Then
        Range("J" & i).Value = CheckBox1.Caption
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Value Then
        Range("J" & i).Value = CheckBox2.Caption
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If CheckBox3.Value Then
        Range("J" & i).Value = CheckBox3.Caption
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If CheckBox4.Value Then
        Range("J" & i).Value = CheckBox4.Caption
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If CheckBox5.Value Then
        Range("J" & i).Value = CheckBox5.Caption
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If CheckBox6.Value Then
        Range("J" & i).Value = CheckBox6.Caption
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If CheckBox7.Value Then
        Range("J" & i).Value = CheckBox7.Caption
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If CheckBox8.Value Then
        Range("J" & i).Value = CheckBox8.Caption
        i = i + 1
    End If

    For e = i To 8
        Range("J" & e).Value = ""
    Next

End Sub
```

This sample it's on the same page, but you need only to add the reference in the range

```
Sheets(2).Range ...
```

You can call directly in the button in the Sheet2 the sub UpdateCheck. Or you can autoupdate adding the code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   UpdateCheck
End Sub
```

for every checkbox in the sheet. 
If you want to use to copy from a bigger data or use in a filter, it's a little bit more complicated...
I don't understand the use of BROWSE Button...

Comment: Thanks for the input. Really Helpful. Hope that my Edited Question will clear the func of the Browse Button.